# Покажите простые примеры использования лямбда-выражений в C++

Tags: c++, лямбда-выражение

Изучаю лямбда-выражения, но не совсем представляю когда уместно их использовать.

Я знаю, что они отлично сочитаются с функциями наподобе std::find_if(), std::count_if().
А можно увидеть другие примеры?

Когда вообще уместно использовать лямбду заместо обычной функции?

Comment: Грубо - там, где она мелкая и разовая :)

Comment: @Harry Там, где определение обычной функции было бы ресурсозатратнее?)

Comment: Лябда-выражения не позволяют делать ничего такого, что было бы невозможно до их введения в язых. По сути это альтернативный, более короткий, синтаксис для создания функций или функциональных объектов (т.е. когда перегружен оператор ()). В принципе их можно вообще не использовать - избавите себя от крякозябров в стеке вызовов при отладке.

Comment: Или где обычная функция не проходила бы - лямбда может ведь не только получать аргументы, но и *захватывать* значения... Понятно, что это можно сделать функтором, но лямбда - явно короче.

Comment: обычную функцию нельзя объявить в другой функции, а лямбду - можно. Вот для этой цели и подходит, в том числе.

Comment: Лямбда все равно будет раскрыта в статическую функцию для единицы трансляции.